# error parsing app.yaml for GAE/Java when specifying servlet for handler

Tags: google-app-engine, yaml

I'm trying to switch over to using app.yaml instead of web.xml and app-engine-web.xml.  I've attempted to follow the documentation faithfully, but I'm getting an error from `appconfig.cmd update <my-war-directory>` that says

```
Reading application configuration data...
Bad configuration: Line 18, column 13: Error setting property 'handlers' on class: com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppYaml
  Caused by: Line 18, column 13: Error setting property 'handlers' on class: com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppYaml
Please see the logs [C:\Users\<blah blah>\appcfg3710135744474388957.log] for further information.
```

In the indicated log file, I see a stack dump with the line:

```
com.google.appengine.repackaged.net.sourceforge.yamlbeans.tokenizer.Tokenizer$TokenizerException: Line 18, column 13: Found a mapping value where it is not allowed.
```

Here's my file (with line numbers manually added):

```
1  application: my-app
2  version: 1
3  runtime: java
4  threadsafe: true
5
6  public_root: /static
7
8  static_files:
9   - include: /**
10
11 welcome_files:
12  - index.html
13
14 system_properties:
15   java.util.logging.config.file: WEB-INF/logging.properties
16  
17 handlers:
18   - url: /user/*
19      servlet: org.restlet.ext.servlet.ServerServlet
20      name: user
21      init_params:
22        org.restlet.application: com.my-app.server.resource.user.UserApplication
23        org.restlet.clients: HTTP HTTPS
```

After experimenting with some YAML validators on the web, I actually think it is complaining about line 19, where column 13 points to the ":" character after "servlet".  But this usage looks totally consistent with the documentation at https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/configyaml/appconfig_yaml#Required_Elements

I'm sure I'm doing something stupid, but I'm stumped.

Comment: ugh.  After suspecting some invisible whitespace-related issue, I decided to just type it in again from scratch, and it worked.  Then, comparing to the previous version, I determined that the problem was due to the fact that the "servlet" line was indented one extra space.  It needs to line up under the "u" in "url" above it.  I guess if I was more familiar with YAML this might be obvious, but as a YAML noob the error was not helpful.  Plus, the example at developers.google.com that I followed has the offending indentation.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you switching to .yaml?

Comment: @DaveW.Smith after reading about it, it seemed visually cleaner and more compact (in the case of my app, 61 lines of app.yaml replaces about 150 lines of combined web.xml and appengine-web.xml), so I thought I'd give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I noted above, the culprit was the indentation of lines 19-21 - they need to line up under the "u" in "url" from line 18.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your great input AndyD! The documentation is updated to fix the problematic sample code.

For me, it is also very convenient to use some yaml validator to check the yaml files. For example: 
http://data-lint.herokuapp.com/

Thanks.

Comment: that's great, thanks for fixing the doc.  I wasn't sure where to report that.